# How does dispatching a action creator function work?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Say I have a action creator function like the one below:

```
import {v4 as uuidv4} from uuid;
export const doSomething = (task) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    const id = uuidv4();
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_TASK",
      payload: {id, task}
    })
  })
}
```

What is the logic behind having to wrap it in a `dispatch` method when I am calling it to update the state of a store in another action creator function?
i.e.:

```
import {setAlert} from "./doSomething"
// another action creator
export const anotherActionCreator = () => dispatch => {
  ...
  dispatch(doSomething("Laundry"));
  ...
}
```

When I remove the `dispatch` method wrapping, it would not call the reducer and update the state in the redux store. I am thinking the action is somehow not connected to the store, but I don't understand how. I thought when you call `doSomething("Laundry")`, the dispatch inside it will already update the store -- but somehow it didn't -- why is that?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Redux store only understands how to accept plain action objects passed to `dispatch`, like:

```js
store.dispatch({type: "todos/todoAdded", payload: "Buy milk"};
```

If you pass a function to `dispatch()`, the store will throw an error.

However, middleware wrap up the `dispatch` function, and can intercept whatever's been passed in to `dispatch()`.  This allows middleware to "teach the store how to accept non-action values", such as passing a function to `dispatch(someFunction)`.

This is how the `redux-thunk` middleware works.  It looks for anything that is actually a function instead of an action object, intercepts that function, and calls it.